# How do I use querySelector with data attribute and class both?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

My html looks like this

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-hide" data-controllinganswer="a1ZC2000000O2n3MAC" data-questionid="a1fC20000000VgXIAU" data-id="a1fC20000000VmzIAE" data-selectedanswer="a1ZC2000000O2zxMAC">
```

But when I try to do this

```
this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + e.dataset.id + '"], .slds-show')
```

It still returns me an element, even though there is no class as `slds-show`. Is this the right way of using queryselector with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma `selector1, selector2` says that elements having selector1 or selector2 should match.

If you have a space `selector1 selector2` it will match an element matching `selector2` inside an element matching `selector1`, if you have `selector1selector2` without space, then it matches only an element that matches both `selector1` and `selector2`.

So your selector should be

```js
this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + e.dataset.id + '"].slds-show')
```

Comment: Or, in a more classic writing - `.slids-show[data-id="..."]`